# Associate Loopback interface with VRF

Tags: networking, netplan

I have multiple VRFs in netplan and each of them has an associated physical interface.
Beside this I need Loopback interfaces with different /32 IP addresses and I would like to bind them to specific VRFs.

Is there a way to do this in Netplan?

Comment: What do you mean by "loopback interfaces"? There is only one loopback interface on Linux, lo.

Comment: I'm coming from networking, usually multiple loopback interfaces can be created on routers or one loopback interface with multiple subinterfaces. 
But then this is not an option in Ubuntu?
How about something similar? Some virtual interfaces maybe

Comment: you may want to post your netplan yaml so we can clearly see what it is you're trying to implement.

Comment: The latest version of Netplan (https://github.com/canonical/netplan/releases/tag/0.107) allows creating dummy-devices, which might be what you need here. (see: https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-yaml/#properties-for-device-type-dummy-devices)

Comment: @Slyon thank you, that's what I need!